# How to pass an javascript object to php session?

Tags: javascript, php, session, session-variables

I´m trying to make an online ordering system for a cafeteria and I am having some trouble to update the information into the session.
I have two javascript window variables (orden, precio) and I want to make their outcome a php session. 
$_POST["orden"] and $_POST["precio"] 
How do I do this?

Comment: You can use `$_SESSION` variable to store data into sessions

Comment: AJAX. Please google before asking, there are so many questions similar to this one. You will easily find code.

Comment: I really can not find it anywhere else and using $-SESSION is not the answer since I am transferring information from Javascript to a PHP SESSION